# Categorising data according to one column in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Hi I have a dataset as follows eg:

```
sample    pos    mutation
2fec2     40     TC
1f3c      40     TC
19b0      40     TC
tld3      60     CG
```

I want to be able to find a python way to for example find every instance where 2fec2 and 1f3c have the same mutation and print the code.  So far I have tried the following but it simply returns everything.  I am completely new to python and trying to ween myself off awk - please help!

```
from sys import argv
script, vcf_file = argv
import vcf
vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(open(vcf_file, 'r'))
for record.affected_start in vcf_reader: #.affect_start is this modules way of calling data from the parsed pos column from a particular type of bioinformatics file
    if record.sample == 2fec2 and 1f3c != 19b0 !=t1d3: #ditto .sample
        print record.affected_start
```

Comment: Why you use `pyvcf` parse to read this input file (Since, it isn't the format) ?

Comment: What do you call "the code" that you want to be printed?

Comment: Is there a relation between the format described in the following link and the 3-column dataset that you show ? http://www.internationalgenome.org/wiki/Analysis/vcf4.0/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your data is in the format you describe and not VCF.

You can try to simply parse the file with standard python techniques and for each (pos, mutation) pair, build the set of samples having it as follows:

```
from sys import argv
from collections import defaultdict
# More convenient than a normal dict: an empty set will be
# automatically created whenever a new key is accessed
# keys will be (pos, mutation) pairs
# values will be sets of sample names
mutation_dict = defaultdict(set)
# This "with" syntax ("context manager") is recommended
# because file closing will be handled automatically
with open(argv[1], "r") as data_file:
    # Read first line and check headers
    # (assert <something False>, "message"
    # will make the program exit and display "message")
    assert data_file.readline().strip().split() == ["sample", "pos", "mutation"], "Unexpected column names"
    # .strip() removes end-of-line character
    # .split() splits into a list of words
    # (by default using "blanks" as separator)
    # .readline() has "consumed" a first line.
    # Now we can loop over the rest of the lines
    # that should contain the data
    for line in data_file:
        # Extract the fields
        [sample, pos, mutation] = line.strip().split()
        # add the sample to the set of samples having
        # this (pos, mutation) combination
        mutation_dict[(pos, mutation)].add(sample)
    # Now loop over the key, value pairs in our dict:
    for (pos, mutation), samples in mutation_dict.items():
        # True if set intersection (&) is not empty
        if samples & {"2fec2", "1f3c"}:
            print("2fec2 and 1f3c share mutation %s at position %s" % (mutation, pos))
```

With your example data as first argument of the script, this outputs:

```
2fec2 and 1f3c share mutation TC at position 40
```

Comment: My solution might not be practical if you work with huge data (there will be too many (pos, mutation) combinations, so the dictionary will use too much memory)

Comment: Thankyou your answer helped me to adapt a script which works  - my data was actually in real VCF format I was just simplifying it as it's quite a confusing format in its own right especially for non-biologists!

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
from sys import argv
script, vcf_file = argv
import vcf
vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(open(vcf_file, 'r'))

# Store our results outside of the loop
fecResult = ""
f3cResult = ""

# For each record
for record.affected_start in vcf_reader: 
    if record.sample == "2fec2":
        fecResult = record.mutation
    if record.sample == "1f3c":
        f3cResult = record.mutation

# Outside of the loop compare the results and if they match print the record.
if fecResult == f3cResult:
    print record.affected_start
```